# UISearchBar iOS returning error of index out of range

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchbar

I have spent about 3 hours trying to get this UISearchbar to work. I have a custom class of `Notes` which has a property of `.name`. I am trying to filter the data (an array of notes) by the property `.name`. I have implemented the `delegate` and instantiated a second filtered array as well as all required protocol requirements. I can't however seem to get my search function to return the correct data. Below is the current code I am using. It builds fine, however when I start typing in the search bar I get an error of `index out range`, this happens at the line in below with the comment attached. This is being done from within a view controller and a table controller inside of it.

```
var notes = [Notes]()
var searchActive : Bool = false
var filtered = [Notes]()

/// these above vars are global /// 

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = notes.filter(){ (Notes) -> Bool in
        let range = Notes.name.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range != nil
    }
    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var note: Notes

    if(searchActive){
        //// THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN /////
        note = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        note = notes[indexPath.row]
    }

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NoteCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? NoteCell {
        cell.configureCell(note: note)
        return cell
    } else {
        return NoteCell()
    }

}
```

Comment: You can only remove if condition from "searchBar:textDidChange" method and searchbar.text = "" add this line in "searchBarCancelButtonClicked" method, your problem has been solved.

Comment: If you want more clarification please add your all view controller code, I will suggest what is wrong in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reload the `tableView` also after setting `searchActive` to `false` in methods `searchBarTextDidEndEditing`, `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` and `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`.

**Note:** Don't set `searchActive` to `true` in methods `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` because if you taped on the searbar and didn't type anything and try to scroll then also you will get index out of bounds crash.

**Edit:** Check `numberOfRowsInSection` is properly implemented or not.

```
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
    if searchActive {
        return filtered.count
    }
    return notes.count
}
```

Comment: I have tried added that but it still seems to error out. It seems that when I enter text that it is finding, so for example one `note.name` is equal to "test". and the second `note.name` is equal to "text", i can type in "te", but as soon as i enter "s" trying to type "test" it errors out

Comment: yup.... seemed like i was missing something simple. Thanks for keeping me from beating my head on the desk for much longer.

Comment: @user1881482 Welcome mate :)